# parsing stringstream iterating through content not working

Tags: c++, parsing, stringstream, peek

I have the following code to retrieve double values from a streamstring but for some reason I can't iterate through the stream, it just loads the first value in the stream and then exits the while, in both cases (i and f) see below:

```
std::string pois_fija_lista = argv[11];
    std::string pois_flotante_lista= argv[12];

    std::vector<double> vector_pois_fija(8), vector_pois_flotante(8);
    std::stringstream ss_fija(pois_fija_lista), ss_flotante(pois_flotante_lista);

    int i=0;
    while (ss_fija >> i || ss_fija.eof())
    {
        vector_pois_fija.push_back(i);

        if (ss_fija.peek() == ';')
            ss_fija.ignore();
    }

    int f=0;
    while (ss_flotante >> f || ss_flotante.eof())
    {
        vector_pois_flotante.push_back(f);

        if (ss_flotante.peek() == ';')
            ss_flotante.ignore();
    }
```

Just for reference, the values in the stringstream taken from the argv are:
-461.3175;-417.031983203125;-523.8393;-417.031983203125;-491.6311;-518.393083203125;-490.6838;-512.709283203125

and

-102.287501220703;-54.613701647949;-164.809301220703;-54.613701647949;-132.601101220703;-155.974801647949;-131.653801220703;-150.291001647949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract into a double instead of an int otherwise the streams failbit gets set.

You also want to terminate, not continue, on eof. The eof check isn't really needed anyway as converting the stream to a bool will give false on eof anyway.

```
double i = 0.0;
while (ss_fija >> i)
{
    vector_pois_fija.push_back(i);

    if (ss_fija.peek() == ';')
        ss_fija.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Yes, when you create the vector that way 8 default initialized (0.0) values are added and all the ones read from the stream are appended after them. If you want to optimize memory allocation you should call vector::reserve instead.

Comment: Thanks it did the trick. I also modified the vector declaration and removed the (8) since it was causing some troubles in the assignments.